# How can I block access to certain websites on Ubuntu?

Tags: chrome, internet

I would like to block certain websites to improve productivity and avoid distraction. I have found BlockSite (Brave browser extension) to be a very good tool but it has one fatal flaw in that it can be disabled ***very*** easily via the taskbar at the top. I would like a more sturdy solution.

I initially used the method outlined [here](https://bytenbit.com/how-to-block-websites-on-windows-ubuntu-macintosh/) but I found that this method did not emulate the functionality of BlockSite, the latter of which would block every page on Facebook or Twitter (for example), this method of editing the `/etc/hosts` file only ended up blocking `twitter.com` and not all pages associated with Twitter (I could still access, for example, Joe Biden's or Donald Trump's Twitter pages)

What is the best way to completely block certain websites on ubuntu in a way that makes it difficult to unblock them?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a trivial task.

How many sites do you think there are which might be distracting/harm productivity? If its just 2 sites, then adding them to /etc/hosts will work. 20 - yes, that's OK - but we're getting to the point where maintaining that lis going to start getting difficult. At 200 hosts you're going to see some impact on performance.

Running your nameserver as suggested by Fox scales in terms of the technology - but is rather difficult to maintain a large list of sites. Also you need to find a ways to prevent the user from simply pointing the machine at another DNS server (or simply enabling DNS-over-HTTPS in the browser).

There are off-the-shelf solutions for a network of computers - using a pihole router or Squid proxy with blocking lists (have a google for Squidguard). But if you only have a single machine running dhcp off a domestic ADSL serve implementing these will be difficult - you'll need to start the user session in a sepatate network namespace without access to the internet and connect via a proxy running elsewhere on the same host.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Github [bytescout/list-of-procrastination-websites](https://github.com/bytescout/list-of-procrastination-websites) and follow the really simple instructions. Works for Linux & Windows. Specifically under Linux you would edit the `/etc/hosts` instead of the Windows `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` file. Use your `sudo` password.

Comment: Please include instructions rather than just quoting external site as external sites can change over time.

Answer (score 0):

I agree to Justin Solms. I tried something like `*` but it didn't work (`www.google.com`, `www.google.fr` -> `www.google.*`). For performance reasons I understand, maybe there is a workaround.

Anyway it would be bothersome for a personal use. When it is time to enjoy yourself, it's nice to be able "come back" from it. I propose a script that should work for all linux distros. As long as `hosts` is in `/etc/`.

This script only does copies. The init parameter creates (ask if existing) `hosts.prod` (productivity) and `hosts.div` (divertissement, it's French so let's say diversion to stay in english ^^). Then all it does is overwriting `hosts` by the div or prod version.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
# This script inverts the hosts files.
# To be in the productive mode or not.
# -p: productive mode
# -n: non-productive mode
# --init: initialize hosts

PROD_HOSTS=/etc/hosts.prod
DIV_HOSTS=/etc/hosts.div
HOSTS=/etc/hosts

if [ "$1" == "-p" ]; then
    echo "Switching to productive mode"
    sudo cp $PROD_HOSTS $HOSTS -f
elif [ "$1" == "-n" ]; then
    echo "Switching to non-productive mode"
    sudo cp $DIV_HOSTS $HOSTS -f
elif [ "$1" == "--init" ]; then
    echo "Initializing hosts"
    sudo cp $HOSTS $DIV_HOSTS -i
    sudo cp $HOSTS $PROD_HOSTS -i
    sudo echo "# Blacklisted websites" >> $PROD_HOSTS
    sudo echo "127.0.0.1  www.example.org" >> $PROD_HOSTS
    echo ""
    echo "To update your blacklist: `sudo vim /etc/hosts.prod`"
    echo "(`vim` or `nano`)"
    echo ""
    echo "/!\\ Don't forget to run this script after editing!"
    echo ""
else
    echo "Usage: productivity.sh [-p|-n]"
    echo "  -p: productive mode"
    echo "  -n: non-productive mode"
    echo "  --init: initialize hosts"
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is the fastest to implement solution:

https://linoxide.com/tools/chomper-command-line-tool-block-website-linux/

You could also use something like CTparental if you prefer something with a GUI:

https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/ctparental-parental-control-tool-linux/

this guide is a bit outdated, you will need to download the current version from here instead of github:

https://gitlab.com/marsat/CTparental/-/releases

Answer (score -2):

You were on the right track with `/etc/hosts`, dealing directly with hostname resolution. The issue, as you point out, is that you can't wildcard all the subdomains there. For that, you'll need to set up a DNS server.  For example, if you are using BIND you'll first want a zone file like the following:

```
; /var/named/blackhole.zone
@ IN SOA localhost. localhost. (
        2021121301  ; Serial
              7200  ; Refresh
               120  ; Retry
           2419200  ; Expiration
              3600) ; Default TTL
     A    127.0.0.1
* IN A    127.0.0.1
     AAAA ::1
* IN AAAA ::1
```

Then you'll need to make a config file containing domains you intend to block:

```
# /etc/named/blackhole.conf
zone "facebook.com" {type master; file "/var/named/blackhole.zone";};
zone "twitter.com" {type master; file "/var/named/blackhole.zone";};
```

Somewhere in the main configuration, include this file:

```
# main config, probably /etc/named.conf but can vary
#...
options {
        listen-on { 127.0.0.1; }; # localhost only
        forwarders {208.67.222.222; 208.67.220.220;}; # OpenDNS
        # ...
}
include "/etc/named/blackhole.conf";
```

Then assuming your DNS server is configured to be `127.0.0.1` and BIND is running, you can run `rndc reload` in order to blacklist all of the wildcard domains.

Essentially what you're doing here is setting up a **forwarding DNS server** with some of its own (fictional) **authoritative zones** that direct some hostnames to localhost instead of their real locations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Are you aware of any third-party applications (something along the lines of parental control maybe) that can be installed on Ubuntu to add site blocking functionality?

Comment: Since the OP already knows about `/etc/hosts` and requires it to work for subdomains (" I found that this method did not emulate the functionality of BlockSite") explaining how to use `/etc/hosts` to block subdomains is the only possible scope for the answer. As it stands, your answer isn't adding anything the OP doesn't already know.

Comment: @terdon Thank you for your comment. Are you familiar with how to use /etc/hosts to block all subdomains? I have tried wildcarding using "*" e.g. "www.twitter.com/*" but this does not work.

Comment: @user440418 no, sorry, I don't know about this sort of thing at all. I was just pointing out that Fox's answer was not really answering your question since the parts that could actually help you were considered out of scope.

Comment: @user440418 as I mentioned in this answer, you _cannot_ wildcard in `/etc/hosts`. you have to either list every possible subdomain, or use a proper DNS server

Comment: @terdon each DNS server (BIND, dnsmasq, etc) will be set up its own way based on its documentation. I could give a description of my own BIND setup, but the intent here was to give direction rather than shill a specific server tool

Comment: @terdon well, I suppose shilling for one specific tool is better than being entirely useless. I've added a sample BIND configuration that gets the job done